# c++11 thread/mutex implementation in VS2012 - assertion fired

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2012, mutex

I want to move my code from boost- to std-threads. While I thought it should be quite straight forward I'm running into weird problems. The code below is a minimal example which fires an assertion "f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\thr\mutex.c(131):unlock of unowned mutex" with VS2012. Searching for this brings up [older bug reports](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/688797) which (i think) should be already fixed.

```
int result = 0;
std::mutex m;
m.lock();
std::thread t1([&](){
    result = 42;
    m.unlock();
});
m.lock();
std::cout << result << std::endl;
t1.join();
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: You're locking `m` twice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`m.unlock()` requires that the calling thread owns the mutex. Your code does not meet that requirement (as the `unlock()`ing thread never calls `m.lock()`) and so the program's behavior is undefined.

Comment: I'm surprised by that limitation - was never affected by it. I guess that's a good use case for condition variables?!

Comment: It mirrors requirements in other mutex APIs that only a mutex owner is able to give up its ownership. Pthread mutexes and Windows critical sections both have this restriction. What you should use instead depends on what you're trying to use them for.

Comment: @Daniel: Don't use raw mutexes. Use `std::lock_guard` instead for a safe SBRM guard.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The use case here is different. One thread needs to inform another thread when it is done with it's work

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, condition variables are much more appropriate for that use than locks.

Comment: or a `std::promise` maybe